# Python raises SyntaxError on "=" in if statement

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that takes user input and compares it to different command strings. When I attempt to run the program, I get a `SyntaxError` about the line `if method = 'addition':` and IDLE highlights the `=` in red.

```
num1 = input('Enter your first value: ')
num2 = input('Enter your second value: ')
method = input('Which method will you be using? ')

if method = 'addition':
    solveFor = num1 + num2
elif method = 'subtraction':
    solveFor = num1 - num2
else:
    print("Please enter 'addition' or 'subtraction'")
```

Answer (score 7):

The equality comparison operator in Python is `==`.  `=` is a statement for assigning a value to a variable.

Your code has a number of other errors (beginning with the undefined names `num1`, `num2`, sitting there doing nothing at the beginning).  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to brush up on the basics of Python syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tips:

- Python doesn't require you to declare variables like other languages do, as it is dynamically typed, so there is no need to write `num1` at the beginning of your script.
- The single equals sign is used for setting a value (`a = 2`), while the double equals sign is used to compare values (`if a == 2:`).
- You need to place colons after all `if`, `else` and `elif` statements.
- Indentation is important in Python.

You seem to be lacking basic Python knowledge and should really read through a decent Python tutorial. I've been told that this online book is good: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

For reference, here's a fixed version of your code:

```
print "Welcome to PyCalcBasic"

num1 = input("Enter your first value")
num2 = input("Enter you second value")
method = raw_input("Which mathematical operator will you be using?")

if method == "addition":
    solveFor = num1 + num2
elif method == "subtraction":
    solveFor = num1 - num2
else:
    print ("Please enter 'addition' or 'subtraction'")
```

Comment: thanks man, just one extra question, what separates "raw_input" from "input" I see you have set method as raw_input and num1, num2 as standard inputs

Comment: `input()` evaluates the string (`2 + 2` becomes `4`), while `raw_input()` just gives you `2 + 2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Single equals `=` is assignment, double equals `==` is equality testing
2. You need a colon after the condition of an `if` or `elif` statement, or after the `else`