# Generate ramdom numbers that never stop unless user stops it numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a code that generates ramdom numbers over and over without stoping unless the user ask for it to stop.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

def random_numbers():
    n = 0
    while True:
      n = np.random.rand(1, 1000000)
      yield n

for x in random_numbers():
    if x = np.random.rand(1,1000000):
      break
    else:
      print(x)
```

and that is the error code I get:

```
      File "<ipython-input-14-3da1e7717cee>", line 10
    if x = np.random.rand(1,1000000):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python raises SyntaxError on "=" in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756972/python-raises-syntaxerror-on-in-if-statement)

Comment: I tried editing the title to something more descriptive, but it won't let me, probably because the issue is too generic/common.

Answer (score 0):

Equality checking in Python is done with `==`, not just one `=`. A single `=` is reserved for assignment.

Comment: Already tried but I was getting this problem:


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-957c0efea64d> in <module>()
      8 
      9 for x in random_numbers():
---> 10     if x == np.random.rand(1,1000000):
     11       break
     12     else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @NonDeZeusProductionz 1) That's another question entirely. 2) That exact error is quite common on Stack Overflow, try doing some research.